# Detect if the original node failed in tomcat cluster

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, cluster, failover

I have two nodes in a cluster. Node1 initially servers requests. Loadbalancer redirects the request to node 2 if the first node fails. I would like to know if there is a way for the Node 2 to detect if it is getting the request that was supposed for the node 1 or in other words to know if the node1  just failed.

I am using Tomcat 6 with session replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Detect" as in you want your own code to realize that the session was failed over? Why do you need your code to be aware of failover?

If you have set `jvmRoute` for the appropriate Tomcat `Engine`, Tomcat should automatically append `.<jvmRoute>` to the `JSESSIONID` cookie value. Therefore looking at the incoming `JSESSIONID` cookie is one way to detect failover I suppose.